# Toast appended to DOM not showing on show()

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, bootstrap-5, toast

I am trying to use Bootsrap 5's toast component to display response messages after a jquery Ajax call.

In the success portion, I end with this snippet:

```
itsToastTime(response.status, response.message)

let toast = $("#responseToast")
deliciousToast = new bootstrap.Toast(toast)
deliciousToast.show()
```

itsToastTime is defined as such:

```
    function itsToastTime(status, message) {
        // Create the constituent elements of the Toast
        const toastContainerClasses = [
            "toast-container",
            "position-fixed",
            "bottom-0",
            "end-0",
            "p-3",
        ]
        let toastContainer = document.createElement('div')
        toastContainer.classList.add(...toastContainerClasses)
        toastContainer.id = 'responseToast'

        let toastDiv = document.createElement('div')
        toastDiv.className = 'toast'
        toastDiv.setAttribute('role', 'alert')
        toastDiv.setAttribute('aria-live', true)
        toastDiv.setAttribute('aria-atomic', true)

        let toastHeader = document.createElement('div')
        toastHeader.className = 'toast-header'

        let toastHeaderStatus = document.createElement('strong')
        toastHeaderStatus.className = 'me-auto'

        let statusText = document.createTextNode(status)
        toastHeaderStatus.appendChild(statusText)

        let exitButton = document.createElement('button')
        exitButton.className = 'btn-close'
        exitButton.setAttribute('type', 'button')
        exitButton.setAttribute('aria-label', 'Close')
        exitButton.setAttribute('data-bs-dismiss', 'toast')

        let toastBody = document.createElement('div')
        toastBody.className = 'toast-body'

        let messageText = document.createTextNode(message)
        toastBody.appendChild(messageText)

        // Build the Toast from its constituent elements
        toastContainer.appendChild(toastDiv)
        toastDiv.appendChild(toastHeader)
        toastHeader.appendChild(toastHeaderStatus)
        toastHeader.appendChild(exitButton)
        toastDiv.appendChild(toastBody)

        // Append the Toast to the document's container div
        let container = document.getElementById('container')
        container.appendChild(toastContainer)
    }
```

The element is added to the dom in the expected location, but the toast does not dislpay.
Any help would be appreciated

I tried to dynamically create a Bootstrap 5 toast element and add it to the DOM.
The Element is added, with the dynamic text elements, but the toast does not respond as normal
when Bootstrap's show() is called

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're creating a new Bootstrap Toast instance every time you want to show the toast, which can cause issues because the toast element already exists in the DOM. Instead, you should create the toast element once and then update its content and show it each time you need to display a message. Here's an updated version of your code that should work:

```
// Define a variable to hold the toast element
let toastEl = null;

function itsToastTime(status, message) {
  // If the toast element doesn't exist, create it
  if (!toastEl) {
    const toastContainerClasses = [
      "toast-container",
      "position-fixed",
      "bottom-0",
      "end-0",
      "p-3",
    ];
    let toastContainer = document.createElement("div");
    toastContainer.classList.add(...toastContainerClasses);
    toastContainer.id = "responseToast";

    let toastDiv = document.createElement("div");
    toastDiv.className = "toast";
    toastDiv.setAttribute("role", "alert");
    toastDiv.setAttribute("aria-live", true);
    toastDiv.setAttribute("aria-atomic", true);

    let toastHeader = document.createElement("div");
    toastHeader.className = "toast-header";

    let toastHeaderStatus = document.createElement("strong");
    toastHeaderStatus.className = "me-auto";

    let exitButton = document.createElement("button");
    exitButton.className = "btn-close";
    exitButton.setAttribute("type", "button");
    exitButton.setAttribute("aria-label", "Close");
    exitButton.setAttribute("data-bs-dismiss", "toast");

    let toastBody = document.createElement("div");
    toastBody.className = "toast-body";

    // Add the elements to the toast element
    toastContainer.appendChild(toastDiv);
    toastDiv.appendChild(toastHeader);
    toastHeader.appendChild(toastHeaderStatus);
    toastHeader.appendChild(exitButton);
    toastDiv.appendChild(toastBody);

    // Save the toast element to the variable
    toastEl = toastContainer;
  }

  // Update the toast content with the new message
  toastEl.querySelector(".toast-header strong").textContent = status;
  toastEl.querySelector(".toast-body").textContent = message;

  // Show the toast
  let deliciousToast = new bootstrap.Toast(toastEl);
  deliciousToast.show();
}
```

With this code, the first time `itsToastTime` is called, it will create the toast element and save it to the `toastEl` variable.
For subsequent calls, it will update the toast content and show it using the same `toastEl` element. This should prevent any issues with creating multiple toast elements and ensure that the toast is displayed correctly.